# How to avoid infinite loop in BFS?

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

Here 's the LeetCode problem [542. 01 Matrix](https://leetcode.com/problems/01-matrix/)

My code will create an infinite loop because it will push every directions into the queue, even if that node has already been visited.
I can't think of a way to solve this problem. Could anyone help?

```
class Solution {
int[][] dirs = { {0,1},{0,-1},{1,0},{-1,0} };
public int[][] updateMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for(int i=0;i < matrix.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length;j++){
            if(matrix[i][j] == 1)
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                BFS(new int[]{i,j},matrix);
        }
    }        
    return matrix;
}

public void BFS(int[] node,int[][] matrix){
    if(matrix[node[0]][node[1]] == 0)
        return;
    LinkedList<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.push(node);
    int step = 1;
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        int[] temp = queue.poll();
        if(temp == null){
            step++;
            continue;
        }
        for(int[] dir:dirs){
            int r = temp[0] + dir[0];
            int c = temp[1] + dir[1];
            if(r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= matrix.length || c >= matrix[r].length)
                continue;
            queue.push(new int[] {r,c});
            if(matrix[r][c] == 0){
                matrix[temp[0]][temp[1]] = Math.min(step,matrix[temp[0]][temp[1]]);
            }
        }
        queue.push(null);
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: "even if that node has already been visited". Then mark node as visited and only push to queue unvisited

Comment: ... and you may need a separate data structure to track which nodes have already been visited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must keep track of the nodes that were already visited. You can either keep the nodes in the list, or move them to a separate `Set`.

The problem you have here is that the nodes are arrays, and you cannot use them in a `HashSet`. I would start by declaring a class `Coordinates`:

```
public class Coordinates {
    public final int row;
    public final int col;

    public Coordinates(int r, int c) {
        this.row = r;
        this.col = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (row + 37*col) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || other.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Coordinates o = (Coordinates)other;
        return row == o.row && col == o.col;
    }
}
```

Option 1: keeping the nodes in the queue

I didn't understand the purpose of adding `null`s into the queue; I just removed this.

```
public void BFS(Coordinates node,int[][] matrix){
    if(matrix[node.row][node.col] == 0)
        return;
    List<Coordinates> queue = new ArrayList<>();
    queue.add(node);
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); ++i) {
        Coordinates temp = queue.get(i);
        for(int[] dir:dirs){
            int r = temp.row + dir.row;
            int c = temp.col + dir.col;
            if(r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= matrix.length || c >= matrix[r].length)
                continue;
            Coordinates newCoord = new Coordinates(r, c);
            if (!queue.contains(newCoord)) {
                queue.add(newCoord);
            }
            if(matrix[r][c] == 0){
                matrix[temp.row][temp.col] = Math.min(step,matrix[temp.row][temp.col]);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Option 2: use a separate `Set`

Now that we have a `hashCode`and an `equals` method, why not use a `HashSet`?

I will leave this as an exercise though.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the node address in a class that can implement hashcode and equals, as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076567/3992939) answer. Node class can be as simple as :

```
class Node {

    private final int[] address;
    Node(int[] address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other == null ||!(other instanceof Node)) return false;
        return Arrays.equals(address, ((Node)other).getAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(address);
    }

    public int[] getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

It allows you to maintain a collection of visited nodes : `Set<Node> visited = new HashSet<>();` 
When `visited.add(node)` returns false, you know that `visited` already contains `node`